# jQuery - Adding field fields dynamically

Tags: jquery

Im trying to implement some code i found on a website which duplicates a file field when you click a href link, the code is pretty much exactly the same from the site, yet its not working at all.

Could someone have a look and let me know where im going wrong.

The complete code is as follows:

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
$(
function(){
    var jAddNewUpload = $( "#add-file-upload" );

    jAddNewUpload
        .attr( "href", "javascript:void( 0 )" )
        .click(
            function( objEvent ){
                AddNewUpload();

                objEvent.preventDefault();
                return( false );
            }
        );
}
);

function AddNewUpload(){
    var jFilesContainer = $( "mpfiles" );
    var jUploadTemplate = $( "#element-templates div.row" );
    var jUpload = jUploadTemplate.clone();
    var strNewHTML = jUpload.html();
    var intNewFileCount = (jFilesContainer.find( "div.row" ).length + 1);

    jUpload.attr( "id", ("file" + intNewFileCount) );

    strNewHTML = strNewHTML
        .replace(
            new RegExp( "::FIELD3::", "i" ), ("mpfile[]")
        );

    jUpload.html( strNewHTML );

    jFilesContainer.append( jUpload );
}
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="mpfiles">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Files:</label>
        <div class="files-box">
            <div class="file sub-file">
                <input class="file-input-area" name="mpfile[]" type="file" size="32" value="" />
                <input readonly="readonly" class="text" type="text" value="click to upload" />
                <a href="#" class="button">view</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="element-templates" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Files:</label>
        <div class="files-box">
            <div class="file sub-file">
                <input class="file-input-area" type="file" name="::FIELD3::" size="32" value="" />
                <input readonly="readonly" class="text" type="text" value="click to upload" />
                <a href="#" class="button">view</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <a href="" id="add-file-upload">Upload another file</a>
</div>
```

The website where i got the code from is here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1375-Ask-Ben-Dynamically-Adding-File-Upload-Fields-To-A-Form-Using-jQuery.htm

Comment: It might be useful to edit this and make a note of the steps you've already tried to diagnose the issue. It would cut down on what people need to look at themselves, and also show that you aren't just putting it here for us to work on it because you are lazy.

Comment: since i can't do it for you, you might want to also double check that you have the correct number of spaces in front of your code.   The makrup language is looking for 4 spaces to decide what is code, and what is normal text.

Comment: Hey All, I figured it out. Sorry about that .... i missed out the ID thingo (#) before the mpfiles Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AddNewUpload(){ var jFilesContainer = $( "mpfiles" );
```

You need a `#` before `mpfiles` ... like this:

```
function AddNewUpload(){ var jFilesContainer = $( "#mpfiles" );
```

Comment: @Chris, heh.. I was too slow.  Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Hmm, im not sure if this is assocciated with this, but adding the new file fields works fine, but when i choose a file from the fields that have been dynamically inserted, it wont display in the little file textbox